# SQL compilation error: schema object identifier 'ALL_VIEWS.TABLE_CATALOG.ALL_VIEWS.TABLE_SCHEMA.ALL_VIEWS.TABLE_NAME' has too many qualifiers

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
with all_views as (select * 
  from information_schema.views 
  where table_schema != 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA')
 SELECT * FROM TABLE(get_object_references(database_name=>all_views.TABLE_CATALOG,
                                 schema_name=>all_views.TABLE_SCHEMA,
                                 object_name=>all_views.TABLE_NAME));
```

I ran the above query in snowflake but getting the below error.

```
SQL compilation error: schema object identifier 'ALL_VIEWS.TABLE_CATALOG.ALL_VIEWS.TABLE_SCHEMA.ALL_VIEWS.TABLE_NAME' has too many qualifiers
```

**What i want to do?**
I want all the available view's source table in a database,

**What i tried?**
below query gives the source table of a particular view under a given schema and database.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(get_object_references(database_name=>'<db_name>',
                                 schema_name=>'<schema_name>',
                                 object_name=>'<view_name>'));
```

And below query gives all the views under a database

```
select * 
  from information_schema.views 
  where table_schema != 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA'
```

So i thought of combining these two queries to give me source tables of all the available views in a database but the above error is thrown.

Is this even the correct way or is there a way to achieve what i want? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Gokhan mentioned, the GET_OBJECT_REFERENCES can only accept "literal" values, and can only be one object, not multiples.

My solution is not perfect, but it can do the trick to get what you are after, by using a SP to return a JSON string, then use RESULT_SCAN & FLATTEN to flatten the result:

```
create or replace procedure get_all_object_references()
RETURNS string
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT 
AS $$
  var query = `
    select * 
    from information_schema.views 
    where table_schema != 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA'
  `
  
  var stmt = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: query} ); 
  var resultSet = stmt.execute(); 
  
  var result = [];
  
  while (resultSet.next()) {
    var catalog = resultSet.getColumnValue(1);
    var schema = resultSet.getColumnValue(2);
    var name = resultSet.getColumnValue(3);
    
    var sub_query = `
      SELECT * FROM TABLE(
        get_object_references(
          database_name=>"${catalog}",
          schema_name=>"${schema}",
          object_name=>"${name}"
        )
      );
`
    var sub_stmt = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: sub_query} ); 
    var sub_resultset = sub_stmt.execute(); 

    if (sub_resultset.getRowCount() <= 0) {
      continue;
    }

    // assume result only returns one row
    sub_resultset.next();

    var sub_result = {};
    sub_result['db_name'] = sub_resultset.DATABASE_NAME;
    sub_result['schema_name'] = sub_resultset.SCHEMA_NAME;
    sub_result['object_name'] = sub_resultset.OBJECT_NAME;
    sub_result['r_db_name'] = sub_resultset.REFERENCED_DATABASE_NAME;
    sub_result['r_schema_name'] = sub_resultset.REFERENCED_SCHEMA_NAME;
    sub_result['r_object_name'] = sub_resultset.REFERENCED_OBJECT_NAME;
    sub_result['r_object_type'] = sub_resultset.REFERENCED_OBJECT_TYPE;

    result.push(sub_result);
  }

  return JSON.stringify(result);
$$;           

call get_all_object_references();

select 
  f.value:"db_name"::string       as DB_NAME, 
  f.value:"schema_name"::string   as SCHEMA_NAME,
  f.value:"object_name"::string   as OBJECT_NAME, 
  f.value:"r_db_name"::string     as REFERENCE_DB_NAME,  
  f.value:"r_schema_name"::string as REFERENCE_SCHEMA_NAME, 
  f.value:"r_object_name"::string as REFERENCE_OBJECT_NAME, 
  f.value:"r_object_type"::string as REFERENCE_OBJECT_TYPE
from table(result_scan(last_query_id())),
lateral flatten(input => parse_json($1)) f;
```

Comment: This is amazing, exactly what i want thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is get_object_references accepts only literal values, therefore your column names are used as "literal". For example, when I run the following query, it accepts my values as literal although they are not enclosed in single quotes.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(get_object_references( DATABASE_NAME => GOKHAN_DB, 
SCHEMA_NAME => PUBLIC,
OBJECT_NAME => TEST_VIEW ));
```

So in your case, it's looking for "ALL_VIEWS.TABLE_CATALOG.ALL_VIEWS.TABLE_SCHEMA.ALL_VIEWS.TABLE_NAME" as the object name after concatenating database, schema and object name.

As a workaround, you may write a JS procedure to call the get_object_references for each view and insert the result into a temporary table.

Comment: Thanks @Gokhan, but in my environment the database wont have a write access(DB will be in client side) i couldn't create functions or tables.